# Vue: Delay option not working with v-popover

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, popover

I use [v-tooltip](https://akryum.github.io/v-tooltip) to create a clickable popover. I'd like the popover to remain visible for a few seconds even if the mouse leaves both the popover and the element triggering it (the button in my example).

This is a simplified example from my code:

```
<v-popover trigger='hover' delay='{ show: 250, hide: 5000 }'>

    <!-- Popover target -->
    <button type='button'>x</button>

    <!-- Content of popover -->
    <template slot='popover'>
        <p>###</p>
    </template>
</v-popover>
```

My problem is that the delay attribute does not have any effect. `trigger='hover'` is working (otherwise the popover would only show on click), but the popover vanishes as soon as I move the mouse away. Shouldn't it remain visible for 5 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the colon before `:delay`. So you are passing just a string not an object.

```js
Vue.use(VTooltip)

new Vue({el: '#app'})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/v-tooltip"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <v-popover trigger='hover' :delay='{ show: 250, hide: 5000 }'>
      <!-- Popover target -->
      <button type='button'>x</button>
      <!-- Content of popover -->
      <template slot='popover'>
        <p>###</p>
    </template>
    </v-popover>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Not `autoHide` though, that doesn't make a difference. I needed to use `:delay` instead of `delay` (Still don't understand why I need to use a colon with `delay`, but not with `trigger`).

Comment: Oh, yes sorry for `autoHide`, let's forget about it :). What's about colon - when you don't provide a colon you pass your value like a **string**, but when you provide - like a **JS expression**. You want to pass an object not a string, like stated in `v-popover` docs.

Comment: I don't get your explanation: How does the colon make the string an object? I thought `:attribute` was Vue specific syntax. I also don't get get why I need Vue attribute binding here. This attribute doesn't need to be reactive.

Comment: If you use the colon, the contents of the attribute are evaluated as Javascript. If you don't, it's a string. `v-popoper` expects `object`.